# TIKZ. Move the arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I have very simple tikzpicture table-scheme and I need to move arrow to the right.. Now it is looks like this:
[image]

But I want to make it like this: [image]

My code:

```
    ... \\ 
        \\
        &
        \node [block_center] (des1) {X[0] OP Y[0]}; 
        &
        \node [block_center] (des2) {X[1] OP Y[1]}; 
        &
        \node [block_center] (des3) {X[2] OP Y[2]}; 
        &
        \node [block_center] (des4) {X[3] OP Y[3]}; 
        \\
    };
    \begin{scope}[every path/.style=line]
        
        \path (x1) -- (op1);
        \path (x2) -- (op2);
        \path (x3) -- (op3);
        \path (x4) -- (op4);
        
        \path (y1) -- (op1);
        \path (y2) -- (op2);
        \path (y3) -- (op3);
        \path (y4) -- (op4); ...
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete but small document with your picture, which we can compile as it is!

Comment: @Zarko OH MY GOD SORRY i didn't think about it!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, since you are new here ...

and for exercise and fun:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 5mm and 3mm,
  start chain = going right,
   box/.style = {draw, thick, 
                 text width=8em, minimum height=3ex, align=#1},
 box/.default = center
                        ]
\foreach \i in {0,1,...,3}
{
    \node  (n1\i)  [box, on chain] {X[\i]};
    \node  (n2\i)  [box=right, below=of n1\i] {Y[\i]};
    \node  (n3\i)  [box, below=of n2\i] {OPERATION};
    \draw[-Stealth] (n1\i) -- (n3\i);
    \draw[-Stealth] ([xshift=2em] n2\i.south) coordinate (aux) 
                                              -- (aux |- n3\i.north);
    \node  (n4\i)  [box, below=of n3\i] {X[\i] OP Y[\i]};
    \draw[-Stealth] (n3\i) -- (n4\i);
}
    \end{tikzpicture}        
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
For exercise here is small variation of original answer, result is slightly more fancy ...

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 5mm and 3mm,
  start chain = going right,
   box/.style = {draw, thick, outer sep=0pt,
                 text width=6em, minimum height=3ex, align=#1},
 box/.default = center
                        ]
\foreach \i in {0,1,...,3}
{
    \node  (n1\i)  [box, on chain] {X[\i]};
    \node  (n2\i)  [box=right, below=of n1\i] {Y[\i]};
    \node  (n3\i)  [box, below=of n2\i] {OPERATION};
    \draw[-Stealth] (n1\i) -- (n3\i);
    \draw[white, thick, densely dashed] (n2\i.north) -- (n2\i.south);
    \draw[-Stealth, 
          transform canvas={xshift=2em}] (n2\i) -- (n3\i);
    \node  (n4\i)  [box, below=of n3\i] {X[\i] OP Y[\i]};
    \draw[-Stealth] (n3\i) -- (n4\i);
}
    \end{tikzpicture}        
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks to you! From now on I will be more attentive to my requests on this stack-exchange

Comment: @chiuki, you are welcome. For exercise I add small variation of original answer. Maybe you'll like it :-)